# Shared drive using trackdown

Tags: r, package, r-markdown, collaboration, google-drive-shared-drive

I am using the R package "trackdown" to share some Rmd files with my collaborators.
I want to share in a Google drive folder that was shared with me and that I am also an editor.

I have been using the following code:

```
trackdown::upload_file = (file = here::here("file-test.Rmd"),
                          gpath = "Name of Folder/",
                          shared_drive = "Name of Folder/")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in `handle_shared_drives()`:
! Can't find the requested `shared_drive`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you done the needed OAuth App Configuration?

Comment: Yes, I have. I managed to same a file in my drive, but not in the shared drive.

Comment: ps: I am not the owner of the folder, but I am an Editor.

Comment: As far as I understand the [documentation](https://claudiozandonella.github.io/trackdown/reference/upload_file.html), `shared_drive` refers to the name of the drive itself and not the folder the file has to go in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, accessing the "Shared Folder"/"Shared with me" section is not feasible due to restrictions in Google APIs. This problem is more thoroughly discussed in the following question:
[Google API to create/update files on 'Shared with me' folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434031/google-api-to-create-update-files-on-shared-with-me-folders)

If you want to use trackdown in a shared folder, there are two options available to you:

Create a folder and share it with others.
Utilize a shared drive, which is distinct from a shared folder. Note that only certain plans allow the creation of shared drives.